# Div not responding to height

Tags: html, css, height, viewport

I have my whole content wrapped up in a Div, but for some reason my #main-content doesn't respond to any of the heights I'm setting. In this case I want my #main-content to be 100vh

HTML

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="overlay"></div>

    <header id="main-header">
        <div class="slider-container">

           /* MORE CODE HERE */

        </div>
    </header>
   
    <div id="content-bottom">

       /* MORE CODE HERE */
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html, body {
position: relative;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
#overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index: 997;
display: none;
}
#main-content {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: pro tip: you can use a language identifier to highlight your css code

Answer (score 0):

`#main-content` will appear to not respond to height adjustments while the height of one of its children is set to `100vh`. Try changing the height of `#overlay` to fill the height of `#main-content` with `height: 100%`.

```
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 997;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working correctly #main-content is 100vh high. Try to run snippet.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
html, body {
position: relative;
scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
font-family: 'Spartan', sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
}
#overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
z-index: 997;
display: none;
}
#main-content {
background:yellow;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="overlay"></div>

    <header id="main-header">
        <div class="slider-container">

           /* MORE CODE HERE */

        </div>
    </header>
   
    <div id="content-bottom">

       /* MORE CODE HERE */
    </div>
</div>
```